# Pandas retrieve values based on columns in df1 that represents intervals from df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got this structured pandas dataframe DF1:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'name': ['A', 'B'], 'ex': ['A1', 'B1'], 'init': ['1,3,5,7,', '10,12,15,17,20,'], 'end':['2,4,6,8,', '15,18,21,24,32']}, columns=['id', 'name', 'ex', 'init', 'end'])
print df

id  name  ex   init               end
1    A    A1   1,3,5,7,           2,4,6,8,
2    B    B1   10,12,15,17,20,    15,18,21,24,32
...
```

*init* and *end* columns represents intervals *(init-end)* so: A -> *(1,2)*,*(3,4)*,*(5,6)*,*(7,8)*, B-> *(10,15)*,*(12,18)*,*(15,21)*,*(17,24), (20,32)*,...
By the other hand, there is another dataframe DF2 that also represents intervals:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'init': ['3', '16'], 'end':['6', '22']}, columns=['id', 'init', 'end'])
print df2

id   init   end
1     3      6
2     16     22
...
```

Is there any smart and efficient way to check what ranges of DF1 contains the range in DF2? In the example, output will be a new DF3:

```
id  name  ex    ranges
1    A    A1  (3,4), (5,6)
2    B    B1  (12,18),(15,21),(17,24)
```

I'm a bit blocked with this and help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The `init` and `end` columns in `df1` must only be checked against the `init` and `end` columns in `df2` _for rows with the same id_, right? (btw second row of printed `df2` should start with `id` `2` instead of `1` right?)

Comment: Hello @jdehesa, yes only checked for rows with the same id. I fixed the ID for df2, thanks for the warning!

Comment: In df2, init=16, end=22, how does the output come to be these intervals: (12,18),(15,21),(17,24) ?

Comment: (16,22) is partially included in those intervals

Comment: Are numbers always integers?

Comment: Yes, the come as string but actually represent integers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'name': ['A', 'B'], 'ex': ['A1', 'B1'], 'init': ['1,3,5,7,', '10,12,15,17,20,'], 'end':['2,4,6,8,', '15,18,21,24,32']}, columns=['id', 'name', 'ex', 'init', 'end'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'init': ['3', '16'], 'end':['6', '22']}, columns=['id', 'init', 'end'])

df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)

df = df1.copy()
df[['init2', 'end2']] = df2

# Per-row function
def proc_row(row):
    # Make list of int pairs
    intervs = zip(map(int, filter(None, row.init.split(','))), map(int, filter(None, row.end.split(','))))
    # Range object to check numbers are in interval - use xrange in Python 2
    r = range(int(row.init2), int(row.end2) + 1)
    # Discard pairs out of interval
    return list(filter(lambda interv: interv[0] in r or interv[1] in r, intervs))

# Process rows
df['ranges'] = df.apply(proc_row, axis=1)
# Drop unnecesary columns
for k in ['init', 'end', 'init2', 'end2']: del df[k]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   name  ex                                    ranges
id
1     A  A1                          [(3, 4), (5, 6)]
2     B  B1  [(12, 18), (15, 21), (17, 24), (20, 32)]
```

Comment: Let me check with a real example! Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do

```
df['init'],df['end']=df.init.str.split(','),df.end.str.split(',')
df
Out[1915]:
   id name  ex                    init                   end
0   1    A  A1          [1, 3, 5, 7]        [2, 4, 6, 8]
1   2    B  B1  [10, 12, 15, 17, 20]  [15, 18, 21, 24, 32]
s=df.init.str.len()
s
Out[1917]:
0    4
1    5
Name: init, dtype: int64


NewDF=pd.DataFrame({'id':df.id.repeat(s),'name':df.name.repeat(s),'ex':df.ex.repeat(s),'init':df.init.sum(),'end':df.end.sum()})
s2=NewDF.merge(df2.set_index('id').stack().reset_index(),on='id').loc[lambda x : (x['end']>=x[0])&(x[0]>=x['init'])]
s2['New']=tuple(zip(s2.init,s2.end))
s2.groupby(['ex','id']).New.apply(list)
Out[1943]: 
ex  id
A1  1                             [(3, 4), (5, 6)]
B1  2     [(12, 18), (15, 21), (17, 24), (20, 32)]
Name: New, dtype: object
```